# ParseException when having a field name which contains '#' in SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I'm doing a simple operation of inserting some fields of table into another table, both tables are hive tables in databricks, so I'm able to do it with a simple query like:

```
INSERT INTO <BBDD_NAME>.<TABLE1_NAME> (<FIELD_1>, <FIELD_2>) 
SELECT <FIELD_1>, <FIELD_2># FROM <BBDD_NAME>.<TABLE2_NAME>
```

The problem I have is because one of the fields has a '#' inside its name and consequently I get a ParseException Error:

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
mismatched input '#' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}
```

TABLE2 is F0911 from JDE ([JDE table doc](https://jde.erpref.com/?schema=920&table=F0911)) and is being inserted directly into databricks via  spark inferring the schema from its origin. So, table was created with no problem containing the '#' containing field.

Is there any way of avoiding this ParseException Error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using back ticks to escape: `\`<FIELD_2>#\``

Comment: @blackbishop, Can you post it as an answer to help other community members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [backticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-identifiers) to escape illegal identifiers in column names.
This should work:

```
INSERT INTO <BBDD_NAME>.<TABLE1_NAME> (<FIELD_1>, <FIELD_2>) 
SELECT <FIELD_1>, `<FIELD_2>#` FROM <BBDD_NAME>.<TABLE2_NAME>
```